# Transfering node modules to the global location

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if transferring node modules that were installed perhaps in a computer to the global modules folder of another computer will have any effect different from installing directly from the internet in that computer.

Comment: Installed modules can be platform-dependent. So yes, there's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It will. Versions to not match with newer global modules , and if some modules not installed, they don't just work. I don't think it is any sort of good practice. It is recommended to install modules in secondary system traditionally by CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Some node modules are OS dependent. For instance, a lot of libraries work differently in different operating systems and they need to be installed with right privileges and configurations. It might work if you transfer the `node_modules` dir from one system to another that has a similar OS setup but it's generally not advisable.

And of course, there's no caching or anything for `node_modules`. They're just files in folders.